# Quickly create new columns in dataframe using lists - R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data containing quotations of indexes (S&P500, CAC40,...) for every 5 minutes of the last 3 years, which make it quite huge. I am trying to create new columns containing the performance of the index for each time (ie (quotation at [TIME]/quotation at yesterday close) -1) and for each index. I began that way (my data is named temp):

```
listIndexes<-list("CAC","SP","MIB") # there are a lot more
listTime<-list(900,905,910,...1735) # every 5 minutes
for (j in 1:length(listTime)){
  Time<-listTime[j]
  for (i in 1:length(listIndexes)) {
    Index<-listIndexes[i]
    temp[[paste0(Index,"perf",Time)]]<-temp[[paste0(Index,Time)]]/temp[[paste0(Index,"close")]]-1
  # other stuff to do but with the same concept
  }
}
```

but it is quite long. Is there a way to get rid of the for loop(s) or to make the creation of those variables quicker ? I read some stuff about the apply functions and the derivatives of it but I do not see if and how it should be used here.

My data looks like this :

```
date      CACcloseyesterday CAC1000   CAC1005 ... CACclose ... SP1000 ... SPclose
20140105    3999            4000    40001.2       4005 ....  2000   ....  2003
20140106    4005            4004    40003.5       4002 ....  2005   ....  2002
...
```

and my desired output would be a new column (more eaxcatly a new column for each time and each index) which would be added to temp

```
date      CACperf1000       CACperf1005...    SPperf1000...
20140106  (4004/4005)-1  (4003.5/4005)-1 .... (2005/2003)-1 # the close used is the one of the day before 
idem for the following day
```

i wrote (4004/4005)-1 just to show the calcualtio nbut the result should be a number : -0.0002496879

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing what your data looks like and what your desired output would be. Can you please provide those?

Comment: Can you show few lines of `temp`

Comment: are the data `xts` objects?

Comment: I imported the data from a .csv file if it might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to generate every combination of Index and Time. Each Index-Time combination is a column in `temp` and you want to calculate a new `perf` column by comparing each Index-Time column against a specific Index `close` column. And your problem is that you think there should be an easier (less error-prone) way to do this.

We can remove one of the for-loops by generating all the necessary column names beforehand using something like `expand.grid`.

```
listIndexes <-list("CAC","SP","MIB")
listTime <- list(900, 905, 910, 915, 920)

df <- expand.grid(Index = listIndexes, Time = listTime,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$c1 <- paste0(df$Index, "perf", df$Time)
df$c2 <- paste0(df$Index, df$Time)
df$c3 <- paste0(df$Index, "close")

head(df)
#>   Index Time         c1     c2       c3
#> 1   CAC  900 CACperf900 CAC900 CACclose
#> 2    SP  900  SPperf900  SP900  SPclose
#> 3   MIB  900 MIBperf900 MIB900 MIBclose
#> 4   CAC  905 CACperf905 CAC905 CACclose
#> 5    SP  905  SPperf905  SP905  SPclose
#> 6   MIB  905 MIBperf905 MIB905 MIBclose
```

Then only one loop is required, and it's for iterating over each batch of column names and doing the calculation.

```
for (row_i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  this_row <- df[row_i, ]
  temp[[this_row$c1]] <- temp[[this_row$c2]] / temp[[this_row$c3]] - 1
}
```

An alternative solution would also be to reshape your data into a form that makes this transformation much simpler. For instance, converting into a [long, tidy format](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10) with columns for Date, Index, Time, Value, ClosingValue column and directly operating on just the two relevant columns there.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have the feeling that the output won't be in a column (I need a column for all the performance of the CAC at 900, then at 905, ... and the same for MIB, ...). Is there a quick way to create those columns after using your solution ? Also, I need those results for each day and I do not see how your solution provides the results for each day (the order is important)

Comment: Each row `df` holds a set of related column names. The `temp[[this_row$c1]] <- ...` creates a new column from the other two columns. It's the same as your original example.